# What does this javascript code do?

Tags: javascript

this code takes a url as input, but I'm not sure what it does or what's the benefit of doing this

```
var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It fetches the hash value off a URL:

So, if the URL is this: `http://something.com/foo#xyz`, it gets the `xyz`

If there is no hash mark in the URL, this code returns the entire URL (which may not be the desired outcome).

This is probably a safer variation that returns an empty string, when there is no hash value:

```
var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
if (hashPos != -1) {
    return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
} else {
    return("");
}
```

Comment: To be specific, it returns whatever is after the *last* occurrence of the `#` in `url`.

Comment: Just in case sameold is unfamiliar with the use of the hash mark in a URL, it's useful to mention that it is used to bookmark places within the page using the name attribute of an element. When navigating to the page, the browser can scroll to the content identified by the hash.

Answer (score 2):

It returns whatever is after the `#` in the url.

Details:

```
var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' ); // Gets the position of the last # found in the string.
return url.substring( hashPos + 1 ); // Gets a piece of the string starting at the given position (hashpos + 1).
```

Answer (score 1):

It gets everything in the URL after the hash (#) mark.

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/test#somesection";

var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );  
return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );  //returns "somesection"
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns the part of the string from just after the last # character to the end. i.e a location in that page.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
```

This grabs the location of the hash char (#) in the URL string.

```
return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
```

This then returns everything after the location of the hash in the url string.

A result would be the hash tag. This is used alot for AJAX applications, where you would like to keep a page state, and be able to link to that state without actually linking to a seperate page.

An example would be:

```
var recent_hash = "";                       
setInterval(poll_hash, 100); // Initialize our hash polling interval for ajax urls

function poll_hash() {
 if (url.substring( hashPos + 1 ) == recent_hash) { return; }   // No change
 recent_hash = url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
 process_hash(recent_hash); 
}

function process_hash(hash_id)
{
 var ajax_url = '/ajax/link_hash/' + hash_id;
 $('#some_div').load(ajax_url)
}
```